# Get Youtube Live Chat URL and then redirect to that URL

Tags: php, api, youtube

I have been trying to find a solution to easily manage youtube live chat. I have managed to retrieve the link for my youtube livestream chat using this code. 
Is it possible to redirect the page to the generated link?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>YT Live Chat Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php

try {
    $videoId = getLiveVideoID('UCSJ4gkVC6NrvII8umztf0Ow');

    // Output the Chat URL
    echo "The Chat URL is https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=".$videoId;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Echo the generated error
    echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
}

// The method which finds the video ID
function getLiveVideoID($channelId)
{
    $videoId = null;

    // Fetch the livestream page
    if($data = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel='.$channelId))
    {
        // Find the video ID in there
        if(preg_match('/\'VIDEO_ID\': \"(.*?)\"/', $data, $matches))
            $videoId = $matches[1];
        else
            throw new Exception('Couldn\'t find video ID');
    }
    else
        throw new Exception('Couldn\'t fetch data');

    return $videoId;
} ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, basically you want to know how to redirect a page?

Comment: I want to redirect to whatever link is generated here

Comment: echo "The Chat URL is https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=".$videoId;

Comment: Basically i want to redirect to https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=".$videoId;

Comment: and the variable changes every day $videoId; apologies if i am making this confusing i have very basic knowledge of web coding.

Comment: so the link generated looks something like this [link]https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=EcEMX-63PKY

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to just redirect the current page to another by using PHP? If that's the case, you can set a header and change the location like:

`header('Location: https://www.google.com/');`

But you have to set headers before producing any output on your page such as your `<html>` and `<head>` tags. You should set the header before any html code on top of your page or alternatively you can use JavaScript to redirect the page.

Examples from w3schools.com:

```js
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Hope this helps.